# Ethernet port is not stable

Tags: networking, windows-10, motherboard, ethernet

I have just built a PC with motherboard Asus pro gaming H170 with Win10, the motherboard actually offers some awesome features for the ethernet port, The problem is when I connect Ethernet cable successfully identified on PC but from time to time (10min Max) automatically disconnects and reconnects, sometimes it gives me the yellow warning about no internet access when there is actually and I have noticed something even more weird the internet speed with ethernet connected to pc is much much much slower than connecting pc with WIFI !! we all know that Ethernet is more stable and faster so why PC doesn't receive the full potential ?

NOTES to keep in mind:

1. I have already been using this ethernet cable with better connecting
   that WIFI for over a year,from the same place with the same router
   with no any changes.
2. I have tested the ethernet cable on another Laptop and a PS4 both gets the Max speed and stable connection.
3. I have installed the drivers and reinstalled the drivers several times hopefully to fix the issue.
4. Asus doesn't have a good tech support especially in my country thats why I'm here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Hussein, have seen this happen from time to time and find that resetting the TCP/IP stack resolves the issue 99.9% of the time. Open a command prompt as administrator and type "netsh int ip reset" - reboot when completed and retest connection. Also, check if there are any driver updates for your ethernet adapter (Intel Gigabit). Before potentially updating the ethernet drivers, delete all oem*.* files from the %windir%\inf directory - this will force Windows to use those specific driver updates.

Comment: @JimNielsen didn't work out

Answer (score 0):

Check the eventvwr logs and see if there are any messages relating to the network adapter or network services. Also, check the power supply. I've seen (in the field) a faulty power supply cause intermittent network issues. Port failing / restarting. Should show up in the eventvwr logs, if this was the case.

Comment: Hi, I havn't used event viewer before and when I launched it, So I want to ask you where to look exactly for that ? should I go to Windows logs-> System ? and search in the source tab for network adapter or network services?

Comment: You're going to want to look in Windows Logs / System. You can use the actions on the right to 'Filter Current Log..." and filter to see the 'critical', 'warning' and  'error' messages. Then look for ones that are recent and reference the network or ethernet port.